# Execute a command and put the results into a variable... all in a bash script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm working on a bash script that backs up a configuration file before copying over a new file.

Here's what my snippet looks like:

```
mv ~/myStuff.conf  ~/myStuff.conf.bak
cp ~/new/myStuff.conf ~/myStuff.conf
```

Every time this script is run, I'd like there the backup to have a unix timestamp in the filename.  I tried this

```
DATEVAR=date +%s
mv ~/myStuff.conf  ~/myStuff.conf.$DATEVAR.bak
```

But this doesn't work, since the date function doesn't execute and bash sees it as a string, and the resulting file ends up being

```
myStuff.conf.date+%s.bak
```

Any ideas on how to get the results of the date function into a variable?

Comment: Technically, that other one is a duplicate of this as this is 3 years older.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

```
DATEVAR=$(date +%s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--[[z4us|binz--]]

export datevar=`date` # date embedded in backquotes

--[[z4us|binz--]]

echo $datevar

Lun 25 Gen 2016 15:56:14 CET
```

Comment: Besides correctly formatting for code, an explanation of what is going on would improve this answer.

Comment: Well, Nattgew FYI: `export` makes the variable available in the environment to be used in next steps. Backquotes surround a bash-command that will be executed. I thought superusers are supposed to know these basics, but of course we have to think of readers who arrive here via any search engine :-)

Comment: For `bash` you may read any shell and I used the command without parameters to see what is the default.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the variable holding the output of a command. That is already answered.  As for the rest of your example script;

A little shorter version:

```
mv ~/myStuff.conf  ~/myStuff.conf.$(date +%s)
```

No need to set a variable for something you only need or use once.  Also, to be compatible with more shells, you could also use this syntax:

```
mv ~/myStuff.conf  ~/myStuff.conf.`date +%s`
```

It just seems to me that having the datestamp as an extension eliminates the need for the additional .bak in the filename.